# displaying a counter in xamarin

Tags: mono, xamarin-studio

I am trying to display a counter but it is not working here is my code:

```
protected void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditText v2 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText5);
        counter1--; 
        if (counter1 <= 0) {
            counter1 = 59;
            timer1--;
        }

        if (timer1 <= 0) {
            t.Stop ();
        }
        try{
            v2.Text = timer1+ ":"+ counter1;

        }
        catch( Exception e8)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this); 
            builder.SetMessage (e8.Message); 
            builder.Create().Show();
        }

    }
```

` I get this error : e8.Message "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." string

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Invoke your code to the [UI thread](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/) instead.